# Is it possible to customize the activation function in scikit-learn's MLPClassifier?

Tags: neural-network, scikit-learn

Scikit-learn lists these as the implemented activation functions for it's multi-layer perceptron classifier:

```
‘identity’, no-op activation, useful to implement linear bottleneck, returns f(x) = x
‘logistic’, the logistic sigmoid function, returns f(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x)).
‘tanh’, the hyperbolic tan function, returns f(x) = tanh(x).
‘relu’, the rectified linear unit function, returns f(x) = max(0, x)
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to implement a custom activation function? If not, can someone point me to a library where this is possible?

Comment: sklearn wasn't made specifically for this task, so it is missing features like this. I recommend [pyTorch](http://pytorch.org) instead; it's the latest and greatest in the field, and it's simple. [Here's a relevant discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/customize-an-activation-function/1652). Welcome to the site and good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much Emre! I just got pyTorch up and running and am fiddling with the forward function right now

Comment: @pennydreams did you ever get to completing the function and how did you implement it? I am trying something similar and could use some pointers!

Comment: @dsforlife84 As Emre stated, it doesn't seem to be possible to implement a custom activation function in scikit-learn's MPLClassifier. I'd look at tensorflow or pytorch for implementing neural nets with custom activation functions.

Answer (score 2):

Although @Emre's comment that sklearn wasn't specifically made for the task is correct, nothing stops you from introducing another activation function by implementing it in [sklearn/neural_network/_base.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neural_network/_base.py). You should be able to find the file in your installation.

To this end, you would define your single-parameter function and add it in the `ACTVATIONS` list. Refer to the existing implementations for some guidance how to do it.

Comment: Looks like we'd also need to implement its derivative