# Is it possible to customize the activation function in scikit-learn's MLPRegressor?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, activation-function

Similar to [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18647/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-activation-function-in-scikit-learns-mlpclassif) about MLPClassifier, I suspect the answer is 'no' but I will ask it anyway.

Is it possible to change the activation function of the output layer in an [MLPRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html) neural network in scikit-learn?

I would like to use it for function approximation.  I.e.

`y = f(x)`

where x is a vector of no more than 10 variables and y is a single continuous variable.

So I would like to change the output activation to linear or tanh.  Right now it looks like sigmoid.

If not, I fail to see how you can use scikit-learn for anything other than classification which would be a shame.

Yes, I realise I could use tensorflow or PyTorch but my application is so basic I think scikit learn would be perfect fit (pardon the pun there).

Is it possible to build a more customized network with [MultiLayerPerceptron](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_mlp.html#multilayerperceptron) or perhaps from individual layers ([sknn.mlp](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_mlp.html#multilayerperceptron))?

UPDATE:

In the documentation for MultiLayerPerceptron it does say:

> For output layers, you can use the following layer types: Linear or
>   Softmax.

But then further down it says:

> When using the multi-layer perceptron, you should initialize a
>   Regressor or a Classifier directly.

And there is no example of how to instantiate a MultiLayerPerceptron object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to inject a modified initialization, which allows you to set the output activation:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
model = MLPRegressor()
from sklearn.neural_network._base import ACTIVATIONS, DERIVATIVES

def inplace_capped_output(X):
    """Compute a capped linear function inplace.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)
        The input data.
    """
    np.clip(X, -40,40)
    

ACTIVATIONS["custom"]=inplace_capped_output

model._old_initialize=model._initialize
def _initialize(self, y, layer_units, dtype):
    self._old_initialize(y, layer_units, dtype)
    self.out_activation_="custom"
    
model._initialize = _initialize.__get__(model)
```

The binding of the modified initialize function follows [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28060251).

You need to do something similar with regard to DERIVATIVES which is needed due to the backpropagation algorithm.

Be aware that you need to adapt https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L274 because deltas[last] = activations[-1] - y is not true if you provide arbitrary, custom output activations.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I'm just trying it out. Getting the following error: `TypeError: _initialize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dtype'` when I call `model.fit(...)` on this line in `_fit`: `self._initialize(y, layer_units)`

Comment: The signature of the initalize function depends on the version of sklearn. In the newest version there is the dtype argument: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed5584/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L292 Probably you run on an older version. You can fix the problem with your version via removing the two mentions of dtype in the above snippet.

Comment: That was the problem. I upgraded from 0.22.2 to 0.24.2 and now it works perfectly.  Here is [my demo code](https://github.com/billtubbs/sklearn-examples/tree/main) which shows how to change the output layer activation function to 'tanh' using this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I see in the code for the MLPRegressor, that the final activation comes from a general initialisation function in the parent class: `BaseMultiLayerPerceptron`, and the logic for what you want is shown around [Line 271](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L271).

```
# Output for regression
if not is_classifier(self):
    self.out_activation_ = 'identity'
# Output for multi class
...
```

Then during a foward pass this `self.out_activation_` is called ([defined here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L112)):

```
# For the last layer
output_activation = ACTIVATIONS[self.out_activation_]
activations[i + 1] = output_activation(activations[i + 1])
```

That ominous looking variable `ACTIVATIONS` is simply a dictionary ,with the keywords being the descriptions you can choose as a parameter in your MLP, each mapping an actual function. Here is [the dictionary](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/neural_network/_base.py#L98):

```
ACTIVATIONS = {'identity': identity, 'tanh': tanh, 'logistic': logistic,
               'relu': relu, 'softmax': softmax}
```

With all of this information, you might be able to come up with a few ways of putting in your custom function. Off the top of my head, I can't see a quick way to simply provide a function. You could for example:

1. define your function where all the other activation functions are defined
2. add it to that `ACTIVATIONS` dictionary
3. make `self.out_activation_` equal to your custom function (or even a new parameter in `MLPRegressor`
4. cross your fingers it doesn't break something somewhere else
5. run it and solve the inevitable small adaptations that will be necessary in a few places

I'm, afraid I have never looked at the source code of that library before, so cannot give more nuanced advice. Perhaps there is a beautifully elegant way to do it that we have both overlooked.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  If I understand this correctly the default activation for an MLPRegressor is set to `'identity'`.  But `MLPRegressor` object has no attribute `out_activation_` so I guess it isn't exposed as an attribute. Identity (linear activation) may be fine for what I need.  Is there an easy way to confirm what activation it is?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant but the last change to this module in Aug 2017 was to line 271 to use this `is_classifier` method `from ..base import`.  Is `out_activation_` not being created for some reason?

Comment: I raised an [issue in scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11038).

Comment: It is the norm to have a linear activation for the last layer. This basically means no activation, as a linear-transform doesn't really do anything but scale your output. Keras has a linear activation as the end; it just multiplies by `1` - [described here](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense). Here is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908744/is-there-any-benefit-to-having-linear-activation-functions-at-the-last-layer-vs) and [here is a related blog post](https://medium.com/the-theory-of-everything/understanding-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-9491262884e0)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes that's what I want.  I just jumped to the incorrect conclusion that a sigmoid was being used by default and that I couldn't change it.  Then I struggled to find out how to check that it is actually using a linear activation...  But in retrospect I think it is.  I adjusted my training data to go above +1 and below -1 and it still fits so obviously it is not sigmoid.

Comment: Am I right that both MLPRegressor and MLPClassifiers should have an attribute called `out_activation_` to confirm it?  I would hate to raise an issue when I am missing something.

Comment: It seems they don't have it straight after instantiation. Perhaps it is buried somewhere or is only created after you have done further setup with the MLPRegressor object. Afraid I don't know anymore!

Comment: You are correct.  It is created after `nn.fit()` is called and it is `'identity'`.  Still your answer to the question is very good!  Thanks.