# Does MLPClassifier (sklearn) support different activations for different layers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, scikit-learn

According to the documentation, it says the 'activation' argument specifies:

> "Activation function for the hidden layer"

Does that mean that you cannot use a different activation function in different layers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can see from the [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L101) (look at uses of `self.activation`) that the same function is used for all the hidden layers.

You might want to consider the comments to [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18647/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-activation-function-in-scikit-learns-mlpclassif) for alternative approaches, generally being a move away from `sklearn` and towards a deep learning framework.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. But the code you have linked is not available anymore

Comment: Hi @DiliniPeiris, thanks for letting me know. I've updated the link in response to the maintainers of sklearn changing the module name.